# How Can I Get My Flask-based Web App Hosted Online?

Tags: model-view-controller, web-hosting

I'm using the Flask microframework to run the Python back-end of my site with an SQLite database. It all looks fine and well running on my Ubuntu machine. But how and where can I actually host it online with a proper URL as in: "https://appname.io"?

Do web hosts usually provide Linux and SSH capabilities?

Comment: You may find https://www.fullstackpython.com/ and https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ useful, but this is far too broad for SO and we don't provide recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

The 'proper URL' you describe is a domain name, and they can be purchased from many online retailers you'll discover when you Google it.

To host your site you will need an actual server host. Many retailers that sell domain names also sell web hosting, but not all. Essentially, every host will provide you with SSH, FTP, MYSQL and anything you may need to host your site. Linking your domain name is normally done automatically if you're purchase both your domain and hosting from the same retailer. However, if purchasing separately you will have to enter the DNS server information to resolve your host.

Try reading [this article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/) to get a good idea of how to move your project to a host. This article is for WordPress, but you should be able to get the general idea on the process.

Comment: Thank you. I was reading about VPS hosting and how it could be the solution I'm looking for, do you happen to know anything about the matter?